Using getopts and case multiple times
I am sourcing a separate file into my .bashrc. That file contains a function similar with this:
function some_function() {
    if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
        return 1
    else
        while getopts "s:td:" opt; do
            case $opt in
                s) echo 's';;
                t) echo 't';;
                d) echo 'd';;
                *) echo 'default';;
            esac
        done
    fi
}

When I run at command line some_function -s 123, I get the expected result.
When I run the exact same command the second time, it will not enter the while loop but is entering the function.
Can you explain why? Thanks

set OPTIND=1 to reset.

Alternatively, local OPTIND at the start of the function.
